newenvironment with lstlisting and tcolorbox
PROBLEM / QUESTION
I want to type code with lstlisting and tcolorbox, which I can do by having 2 enviornments, but I would rather have only 1 environment.
I know that I could probably imitate a tcolorbox with lstlisting in the example below, but I have other colored boxes designed with titles that I don't feel it can be replicated with lstlisting.
I tried several times with different commands even with \lstnewenvironment. I'm also aware that tcolorbox has its own listing, but I prefer having control over the type of language and therefore the coloring of each reserved word, which I think it's only possible with lstlisting.
So how can I create an environment named code that uses tcolorbox boxes and lstlisting without throwing any compiling errors? (I'm using LuaLaTeX and fontspec, just in case)
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tcolorbox, xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable, hooks}
\usepackage{listings}

\newtcolorbox{colorboxcode}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    center,
    before upper app=\centering,
    halign title=flush center,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=2mm, rounded corners,
    colback=gray, colframe=gray, coltext=white,
    overlay first={
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
    overlay last={
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);}
}

\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numbers=none,
    stringstyle=\color{purple},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,              
    keepspaces=true,                               
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=true,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=4
}

%=====================================================

% 1st ATTEMPT
%\newenvironment{code}{\begin{colorboxcode}\begin{lstlisting}}{\end{lstlisting}\end{colorboxcode}}

% 2nd ATTEMPT
%\lstnewenvironment{code}{\begin{colorboxcode}}{\end{colorboxcode}}

% 3rd ATTEMPT
%\lstnewenvironment{codelst}{\begin{colorboxcode}}{\end{colorboxcode}}
%\newenvironment{code}{\begin{colorboxcode}\begin{codelst}}{\end{codelst}\end{colorboxcode}}

%=====================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{colorboxcode}
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    return 0; // opcional
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{colorboxcode}


%\begin{code}
%for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
%   if (a[i] == b)
%       return true;
%return false;
%\end{code}


\end{document}


You can use \NewTCBListing to create a new environment which combines a lstlisting and a tcolorbox:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins

\usepackage{tcolorbox, xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable, hooks, listings}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numbers=none,
    stringstyle=\color{purple},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,              
    keepspaces=true,                               
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=true,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=4
}

%=====================================================

\NewTCBListing{code}{}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    center,
    before upper app=\centering,
    halign title=flush center,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=2mm, rounded corners,
    colback=gray, colframe=gray, coltext=white,
    overlay first={
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
    overlay last={
        \draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
    listing only
}

%=====================================================

\begin{document}


\begin{code}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   if (a[i] == b)
       return true;
return false;
\end{code}


\end{document}



It does compile, but the colors aren't right, I removed the coltext =white but now is all black, any idea?

@Agente156 That are the colours from your colorboxcode environment.
